# MSBuild can't create ZipFile inside ZipProjectTarget

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I'm developing VisualStudio 2012 extension with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826178.aspx instruction.

Everything works fine locally.

But when I try to build this solution with TFS I get this error:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets (991): Zip error: Failed to create the zipfile C:\Builds\1\1CMobileClient\Release\Sources\Sources\<..>.zip.*

Server:
TFS 2012 + VS 2012 SDK

TFS LOG part:

14:49:07.238     3>Target "CalculateZipFiles: (TargetId:77)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" from project "C:\Builds\1\<..>.csproj" (target "ZipProjects" depends on it):
                   Task "CalculateZipItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(ZipProject.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(ZipProject)' != '') was evaluated as (''!='' AND 'Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\MobileApp.vstemplate;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Форма.xml;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Configuration.xml;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp__TemplateIcon.ico;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\ФормаМодуль.cs;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Главный.bp;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\MobileApp.mobproj;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp.vstemplate;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\Configuration.xml;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\Главный.bp;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp.mobproj;Templates\Projects\MobileApp__TemplateIcon.ico' != '').
                   Using "CalculateZipItems" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.Build.Tasks.dll".
                   Task "CalculateZipItems" (TaskId:43)
                   Done executing task "CalculateZipItems". (TaskId:43)
                   Task "CalculateZipItems" (TaskId:44)
                   Done executing task "CalculateZipItems". (TaskId:44)
                   Task "CalculateZipItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(ZipItem.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(ZipItem)' != '') was evaluated as (''!='' AND 'Templates\Items\Process\Process.vstemplate;Templates\Items\Process\Процесс.bp;Templates\Items\Process__TemplateIcon.ico' != '').
                   Task "CalculateZipItems" (TaskId:45)
                   Done executing task "CalculateZipItems". (TaskId:45) 14:49:07.240     3>Done building target "CalculateZipFiles" in project "<...>Project.csproj".: (TargetId:77) 14:49:07.240     3>Target "ZipProjects: (TargetId:78)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" from project "C:\Builds\1\1CMobileClient\Release\Sources\Sources\<...>.csproj" (target "PrepareForRun" depends on it):
                   Task "Message" (TaskId:46)
                     Zipping ProjectTemplates (TaskId:46)
                   Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:46)
                   Task "ZipItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_ZipProject.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(_ZipProject)' != '') was evaluated as (''!='' AND 'Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\MobileApp.vstemplate;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Форма.xml;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Configuration.xml;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp__TemplateIcon.ico;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\ФормаМодуль.cs;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\Главный.bp;Templates\Projects\HelloWorldMobileApp\MobileApp.mobproj' != '').
                   Task "ZipItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_ZipProject.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(_ZipProject)' != '') was evaluated as (''!='' AND 'Templates\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp.vstemplate;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\Configuration.xml;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\Главный.bp;Templates\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp.mobproj;Templates\Projects\MobileApp__TemplateIcon.ico' != '').
                   Using "ZipItems" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.Build.Tasks.dll".
                   Task "ZipItems" (TaskId:47)
                     Zipping C:\Builds\1\1CMobileClient\Release\Sources\Sources\<..>\obj\Release\HelloWorldMobileApp.zip... (TaskId:47) 14:49:07.253     3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(991,5): error : Zip error: Failed to create the zipfile C:\Builds\1\1CMobileClient\Release\Sources\Sources\<..>\obj\Release\HelloWorldMobileApp.zip. 
Done executing task "ZipItems" -- FAILED. (TaskId:47)

Targets:

```
<Target Name="ZipProjects"
         DependsOnTargets="$(ZipFilesDependsOn)"
         Condition="'@(_ZipProject)' != '_'">
    <Message Text="Zipping ProjectTemplates"/>
    <!--
      There are 2 options for using this task:
        1) specifying a rootpath on each item
        2) using the directory of the item as the rootpath

      Note: the name of the zip file will be based on the rootpath
    -->
    <!--Project using RootPath-->
    <ZipItems
        Condition="'%(_ZipProject.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(_ZipProject)' != ''"
        Files="@(_ZipProject)"
        Action="New"
        OutputSubPath="%(_ZipProject.OutputSubPath)"
        Culture="%(_ZipProject.Culture)"
        ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        RootPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(_ZipProject.RootPath)"
        ZipDefaultLanguage="$(VsTemplateLanguage)"
        ZipLanguage="%(_ZipProject.Language)"
        ZipFile="%(_ZipProject.ZipFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="IntermediateZipProject"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </ZipItems>

    <!--Project using Directory-->
    <ZipItems
        Condition="'%(_ZipProject.RootPath)'=='' AND '@(_ZipProject)' != ''"
        Files="@(_ZipProject)"
        Action="New"
        OutputSubPath="%(_ZipProject.OutputSubPath)"
        Culture="%(_ZipProject.Culture)"
        ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        RootPath="%(_ZipProject.RootDir)%(_ZipProject.Directory)"
        ZipDefaultLanguage="$(VsTemplateLanguage)"
        ZipLanguage="%(_ZipProject.Language)"
        ZipFile="%(_ZipProject.ZipFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="IntermediateZipProject"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </ZipItems>

    <!--
      Copy the generated templates to the deployment folder.
    -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateZipProject)"
          DestinationFiles="@(IntermediateZipProject->'$(ZipProjectOutput)\%(Language)\%(OutputSubPath)\%(Culture)\%(FileName)%(Extension)')"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          Condition="'$(DeployVSTemplates)'=='true'" />

    <!--
      Copy the generated templates to the output folder.
    -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateZipProject)"
          DestinationFiles="@(IntermediateZipProject->'$(OutDir)\ProjectTemplates\%(Language)\%(OutputSubPath)\%(Culture)\%(FileName)%(Extension)')"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          Condition="'$(CopyZipOutputToOutputDirectory)'=='true'" >
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="_ZipProjectOutDir"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </Copy>

    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) -&gt; @(_ZipProjectOutDir->'%(FullPath)')" />

  </Target>

  <Target Name="ZipItems"
          DependsOnTargets="$(ZipFilesDependsOn)"
          Condition="'@(_ZipItem)' != '_'">

    <Message Text="Zipping ItemTemplates"/>

    <!--
      There are 2 options for using this task:
        1) specifying a rootpath on each item
        2) using the directory of the item as the rootpath

      Note: the name of the zip file will be based on the rootpath
    -->

    <!--Item using RootPath-->
    <ZipItems
        Condition="'%(_ZipItem.RootPath)'!='' AND '@(_ZipItem)' != ''"
        Files="@(_ZipItem)"
        Action="New"
        OutputSubPath="%(_ZipItem.OutputSubPath)"
        Culture="%(_ZipItem.Culture)"
        ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        RootPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(_ZipItem.RootPath)"
        ZipDefaultLanguage="$(VsTemplateLanguage)"
        ZipLanguage="%(_ZipItem.Language)"
        ZipFile="%(_ZipItem.ZipFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="IntermediateZipItem"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </ZipItems>

    <!--Item using Directory-->
    <ZipItems
        Condition="'%(_ZipItem.RootPath)'=='' AND '@(_ZipItem)' != ''"
        Files="@(_ZipItem)"
        Action="New"
        OutputSubPath="%(_ZipItem.OutputSubPath)"
        Culture="%(_ZipItem.Culture)"
        ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        RootPath="%(_ZipItem.RootDir)%(_ZipItem.Directory)"
        ZipDefaultLanguage="$(VsTemplateLanguage)"
        ZipLanguage="%(_ZipItem.Language)"
        ZipFile="%(_ZipItem.ZipFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="IntermediateZipItem"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ZipFile" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </ZipItems>

    <!--
      Copy the generated templates to the deployment folder.
    -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateZipItem)"
          DestinationFiles="@(IntermediateZipItem->'$(ZipItemOutput)\%(Language)\%(OutputSubPath)\%(Culture)\%(FileName)%(Extension)')"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          Condition="'$(DeployVSTemplates)'=='true'" />

    <!--
      Copy the generated templates to the output folder.
    -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateZipItem)"
          DestinationFiles="@(IntermediateZipItem->'$(OutDir)\ItemTemplates\%(Language)\%(OutputSubPath)\%(Culture)\%(FileName)%(Extension)')"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          Condition="'$(CopyZipOutputToOutputDirectory)'=='true'" >
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="_ZipItemOutDir"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </Copy>

    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) -&gt; @(_ZipItemOutDir->'%(FullPath)')" />

  </Target>
```

Comment: Could you post the markup for the ZipProjects target?

Comment: Markup like this.
<ItemGroup>
    <ZipProject Include="Templates\Projects\ConsoleApp\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <ZipProject Include="Templates\Projects\ConsoleApp\Program.cs" />
    <ZipProject 
Include="Templates\Projects\ConsoleApp\SimpleProject.ico" />
    <ZipProject
 Include="Templates\Projects\ConsoleApp\SimpleProject.vstemplate" />
    <ZipProject 
 Include="Templates\Projects\ConsoleApp\SimpleProject.zzproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Could you take another look for a &lt;Target /&lt; node with a name attribute of "ZipProjects"?  Should be referenced in "C:\Builds\1\<..>.csproj"

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Nick.
I have removed part of the path to make log shorter. In real log there is a folder name.

Comment: In that folder is a .csproj file.  That is an msbuild file, and that log is reporting an error on a target in that file.  What I wanted was for you to post the "ZipProjects" TARGET, not the "ZipProject" ItemGroup.

Comment: I have updated the post with ZipProject targets.

Comment: I have found the problem.

Templates which was the part of ZipProject have file names in russian. When I translate them to english the solution builds sucessfully on the TFS server. But why i can't use russian file Names? maybe there is some property?

Comment: It could be a localization bug in the ZipProject target.